# Compiler version error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: solidity, compiler, version-pragma

I started getting this error...

```
Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.3+commit.9bfce1f6.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

...a few days ago on the following line of code only:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
```

Anyway, this seems to be compiling without issues.

Anybody knows what may be causing this and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: What environment are you working on ?

Comment: What do you mean with environment? I am using Visual Studio Code with `solidity` extension.

Comment: Environment refers to the tools you are using to write the code. Like remix, hardhat, truffle, foundry. I assume you are using hardhat.

This error might be coming from the hardhat config file because of different pragma versions in your smart contract and the config file.

Comment: Yes, I am using `hardhat` for compilation.

Comment: What version of of Solidity do you have specified inside hardhat.config file?

Comment: Version: 0.8.17

Comment: So as you said it compiled successfully, which means that the version was correct.
I think the reason for the previous failure would have been the wrong version in the hardhat config file. 
If it has compiled then there is no issue:)
Keep building.

Comment: I know it works but it is annoying to have that error message and don't knowing why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of these annoying warnings, the best way is to disable the [solidity extension by Juan Blanco](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity) and enable the [Solidity extension by Nomic Foundation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NomicFoundation.hardhat-solidity).